# Extract text word by word from .pdf file using pdfbox

Tags: pdf, export-to-excel, pdfbox, text-extraction

My object is to extract text from .pdf file and write it into an Excel file without losing text formatting. At this moment, I have been success to extract text word by word with font, size, and coordinates in an array of two dimensions but I have a little problem: distinct words in the same row have been combined into one word.

For example:

020 | 0542 | CD45

it will extracted in same word : 0200542CD45

I can not find where is my error. I need your help.

This is my code:

```
public class PrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper {

    public static StringBuilder tWord = new StringBuilder();
    public static String[][] coordTab;
    public static int p = 0;
    public static String seek;
    public static String[] seekA;
    public static List<String> wordList = new ArrayList();
    public static boolean is1stChar = true;
    public static boolean lineMatch;
    public static int pageNo = 1;
    public static double lastYVal;

    public PrintTextLocations() throws IOException {
        super.setSortByPosition(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = null;
        PDFTextParser pdftext = new PDFTextParser();
        String file_name = "d:/test.pdf";
        seekA = pdftext.pdftoText(file_name).split(" ");
        seek = pdftext.pdftoText(file_name);
        coordTab = new String [seekA.length*2][6];
        try {
            File input = new File(file_name);
            document = PDDocument.load(input);
            if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                document.decrypt("");
            }
            PrintTextLocations printer = new PrintTextLocations();
            List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

            for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
                PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
                PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                if (contents != null) {
                     printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
                }
                pageNo += 1;
            }
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                for (int k = 0; k<= p;k++){
                    System.out.println(k+" : "+coordTab[k][0]+" | "+coordTab[k][1]+" | "+coordTab[k][2]+" | "+coordTab[k][3]+" | "+coordTab[k][4]+" | "+coordTab[k][5]);
                }           
                myxls.close();
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
        String tChar = text.getCharacter();
        String REGEX = "'' ";
        char c = tChar.charAt(0);
        lineMatch = matchCharLine(text);
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            if ((!is1stChar) && (lineMatch == true)) {
                appendChar(tChar);
            } else if (is1stChar == true) {
                setWordCoord(text, tChar);
            }
        } else {
            endWord();
        }
    }

    protected void appendChar(String tChar) {
        tWord.append(tChar);
        coordTab[p][3] = String.valueOf(tWord);
        is1stChar = false;
    }

    protected void setWordCoord(TextPosition text, String tChar) {
        tWord.append(tChar);

        coordTab[p][0] = ""+ pageNo;
        coordTab[p][1] = ""+ roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getX()));
        coordTab[p][2] = ""+ roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getY()));
        coordTab[p][3] = String.valueOf(tWord);
        coordTab[p][4] = ""+text.getFontSize();
        coordTab[p][5] = ""+text.getFont().getBaseFont();

        is1stChar = false;
    }

    protected void endWord() {
        String newWord = tWord.toString().replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
        String sWord = newWord.substring(newWord.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
        if (!"".equals(sWord)) {
            if (Arrays.asList(seekA).contains(sWord)) {
                wordList.add(newWord);
            } else {
                wordList.add(newWord);
            }
        }
        tWord.delete(0, tWord.length());
        is1stChar = true;
        p++;
    }

    protected boolean matchCharLine(TextPosition text) {
        Double yVal = roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getY()));
        if (yVal.doubleValue() == lastYVal) {
            return true;
        }
        lastYVal = yVal.doubleValue();
        endWord();
        return false;
    }

    protected Double roundVal(Float yVal) {
        DecimalFormat rounded = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        String st = rounded.format(yVal);
        Double yValDub = Double.parseDouble(st.replace(",", "."));
        return yValDub;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The missing spaces

The mistake in this regard is that you assume that the gaps between words are created by *empty glyphs extracted as space characters*.

**This need not be the case!**

These gaps can also be created by *explicitly forwarding the x position*.

As you only look at the y coordinate of the text origin (`TextPosition.getY()` in `matchCharLine`) but ignore its x coordinate (`TextPosition.getX()`), you miss such gaps.

### Another issue

You assume the order in which you retrieve the `TextPosition` instances is the "correct" order.

**This need not be the case!**

The glyphs of your text may be drawn in a random order, so you might receive them in a random order.

A completely random order is seldom seen but some degree of reordering is used every once in a while.

### What to do

The PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` class actually already uses fairly well-tested routines for adding spaces where a gap indicates it and for sorting unordered glyphs. By overriding `processTextPosition`, though, you prevented that code from being used.

Thus, you should not replace the `processTextPosition` method but instead override the `writeString(String, List<TextPosition>)` and `writeWordSeparator()` methods.

For automatic sorting of the glyphs simply use `setSortByPosition(true)`.